# How to use a GET variable as a column in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, get

Say my URL is in the format of `www.mywebsite.com/search?keywords=library`.

Aside from using `Page Level 1` or `Page Level 2`, is there any way I could specifically get the value of a certain GET variable to be the column of my Google Analytics table?

I currently have this table (see below), but I'm using a `Page Level` column which I think is kind of a cheat. I'd prefer if there was a method to just pull through a specific section of the URL.

[image]

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by a GET variable?

Comment: @nyuen, public variables set in the URL. In this case, the variable is "keywords" with the value "library".

Comment: If those are not what they're called, then please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom dimension in analytics. Go to your property settings -> custom definitions -> custom dimensions -> new. Give it a name (that will appear as column label in your reports). Since the keyword is part of the url hit level scope seems the best fit (meaning that your dimension is associated with a specific user interaction - you could also choose to tie it to the complete session).

If you create the custom dimension it will have a numeric index which you use in your tracking code together with the "dimension" keyword. The following example assumes you have created your first dimension (index 1) and are using php:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'dimension1':  "<?php echo filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'keywords', FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED); ?>"
});
```

(you can use another/better filter but do not put the variable directly into your page).

Now the value is send along with the pageview. Custom dimension do not show up in the standard reports, but you can use them in custom reports or  set them as secondary dimensions in your standard reports.

Comment: I've added said code (readjusted the value of `dimension1` of course). On a side note, if I wanted to do something like this but for `onclick` events, should I use the same code and add it in the `onclick` event handler, or is `ga('send', 'pageview', ...)` inappropriate for this task?

Comment: I think you would track clicks with event tracking rather than pageviews, but the principle is the same.